# Hive split on number of characters

Tags: string, split, hive

I have a file continuous with random character data with no delimiter and no new line character.

Ex. "aaaaabbbbbcccccdddddeeeeefffff..."

I need to split this into 5 character columns in Hive into 3 columns like:

aaaaa,bbbbb,ccccc
ddddd,eeeee,fffff

I've tried below options but all of them doesn't seem to work because there is no delimiter.

1. `select substr(data,1,5)first_col, substr(data,6,5)second_col, substr(data,11,5)third_col from testdb1.example_table`
   This will give me first row correctly but not able to figure out how can i scale this to work on for next rows.
2. Using regexp_extract but again because there is no delimiter to find out 2nd row it doesn't seem to work.
3. Using split or RegexSerDe.

Any inputs will be helpful.

Comment: regex_serde will not help with this because it can not produce new rows. With rows unsplitted split/substr/regexp_extract will deal with the whole file content as single line, even if it works, it is highly inefficient and will cause OOM on big data  Rows should be splitted before you loading data.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great time to pre-process your data.  Why not run sed on it to add delimiters?
This will add a '\n' every 30 characters

```
sed -e 's/.\{30\}/&\n/g' <file> > <new File>
```

Split the lines into 5 characters groups delimited by ',' rows terminated by '\n'

```
sed -E 's/(.\{5\})(.\{5\})(.\{5\})(.\{5\})(.\{5\})(.\{5\})/\1 , \2 , \3 , \4 , \5 , \6 \n/g' <file> > <new File>
```

These sed is pretty good on files, but not sure how big your file is.

If you don't use sed or something like that you could right your own deserializer.  Here's some links to help with that.

- [Tutorial on it.](https://www.congiu.com/writing-a-hive-serde-for-lwes-event-files/)
- [Hive example code including code use for regex serde](https://github.com/apache/hive/tree/trunk/contrib/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/contrib/serde2).

Comment: Yes, if sed can be used then it can be done easily. I was looking for an answer where if at all we can do it in Hive via regular expression way but i guess that is not possible and if have to do it via Hive then custom SerDe is the only option.

Comment: You have an issue with your lack of row to do it natively.  It's a common enough ask to be able to manipulate files and generate records in a specific way.  Once you are comfortable with this answer, and you feel it is the right answer I'd appreciate you marking it as the answer.

Comment: If you feel this answer was helpful and you are comfortable could you mark it as correct?